# Query layer in ArcGIS Desktop with PostgreSQL not querying data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, postgresql, openstreetmap, query-layer

After some days I was finally able to import OSM data to a PostgreSQL database and connect it with ArcGIS 10.2.2

I can load every piece I want by simple clicking "Add data ..." however a SQL query layer always delivers the complete data rather than selecting the rows.

Here is what I set up first:

[image]

And that's what remains after ArcGIS finished loading the layer:

[image]

I don't understand why it keeps transforming the query expression.

In pgAdmin it shows just fine:

[image]

I am really clueless in this matter and ArcGIS is just so slow loading all the data over and over again (instead of QGIS, where the query is no problem).

Comment: Based on your screenshots, something appears to be missing. For one, I would think you need double quotes around the field name you're querying - ie, "landuse". Following that, if you've constructed the query rather than typing it in, your screenshots aren't showing what you've selected. If you reference the [help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000027000000), I note that if you select a table on the left, the box on the right should show a list of available fields and data types.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Chris. I have typed in the SQL query so that's why you cannot see the tables on the right side of planet_osm_polygon. For now I tried the double quotes but ArcGIS still resists to accept the SQL expression and rather select everything again. Don't have any clue why ...

Comment: Then I suspect it might be related to this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94759/using-postgis-functions-in-arcgis-desktop-for-layer-definition-query/94836#94836

Comment: Hmm sounds familiar, however for that OID I generated the arcgis_ID (consecutive BIGSERIAL than tranformed it to varchar in PostgreSQL as ArcGIS cannot use BIGSERIAL as OID just for display) and set it as primary key. After that ArcGIS never complained about a unique identifier anymore.

Comment: Have you used the Validate button on your query? Does it give any errors? I guess the double quotes aren't needed as in this case the SQL rules are those of the underlying database. I don't know why it would transform the query either, but in looking at what it does, it appears it changes * to all fields and then drops the where part. What if you add that back on to the modified version? Is there anything in the advanced options that might affect it? If you click the table, do any of the fields show as invalid data types? I note the help states the query cannot include such fields.

Comment: Pressing validate does nothing as far as the syntax is valid. I tried with an invalid syntax and an error message appears but there is no positive result of testing (what ArcGIS normally prompts). I will try to fiddle around with the expression to move the SELECT to the back asf but honestly, reading and watching other users' interactions there seems nothing special about my query. Data types are all valid, the only thing I can imagine, that I use a varchar field as primary key rather than an numeric, but that shouldn't be a problem ... Thank you so much for your help so far Chris.

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your question, but have you ever tried to use ESRI "ArcGIS Editor for OpenstreetMap"? It comes with an option to load OSM files, and create either a File Geodatabase, or an Enterprise Geodatabase like PostgreSQL, and fill it with the data. The neat thing about this is, that ESRI by default included an option to store all tagging information, like in PostgreSQL hstore. It is stored in a special database field maintained by the extension. This gives you good access to all tags, although admittedly you need to extract them first before being able to use it in SQL.

Comment: There is also an "Add Incrementing ID Field (Data Management)" tool that may be worth trying to exclude an unique identifier issue: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000184000000

Comment: Thanks Marco. I've been using the ArGIS OSM Editor for quite a while but compared to PostgreSQL it is unfortunately quite slow for keeping data of a country up to date. I still derive network data with it but for the other things I tried to switch to PostgreSQL. Thanks for the tool tip, I will certainly check this out tomorrow and report if it might work out. Thanks for you help ...

Comment: "...but compared to PostgreSQL it is unfortunately quite slow for keeping data of a country up to date." ESRI is working on this, making updates more efficient. See the listed fix / enhancement scheduled for ArcGIS 10.3 for applying diffs: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-osm-editor/issues/59. I also wonder if they will start supporting "augmented diffs", because I don't think they do? That might make a huge difference: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Augmented_Diffs